Why I can't catch and log "Out of Memory" exception?
I'm running .net 6 application as a windows service like this:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\dotnet.exe" c:\MyApp\MyApp.dll

Application is starting like this:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.UseSerilog();
// Configure other stuff
var app = builder.Build();
app.MapControllers();

try
{
    app.Run();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    app.Logger.LogError(ex, "error");
}

Using Serilog for logging.
Recently it started crashing on machines with different hardware without logging any error via Serilog and only writing unclear application event logs:


All I can get out of Report.wer is exception code 0xe0434352 (which doesn't seem to refer to anything specific).
After investigation figured out, that particular dll leaks memory when it performs repeatedly open/close operations (in order to implement plug-and-play for external device) reliably culminating in "Out of Memory" (can see it when running from console) and crash after 6-7 hours.
I tried to subscribe to AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException and log this error via Serilog but it doesn't work when this particular crash reproduces.
// Handler 1
using (var eventLog = new EventLog("Application"))
{
    eventLog.Source = "Application";
    eventLog.WriteEntry($"Unhandled exception {(e.ExceptionObject as Exception)}", EventLogEntryType.Error, 1000);
}

// Handler 2 (via Serilog)
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (o, e) =>
{
    app.Logger.LogError((e.ExceptionObject as Exception), "Unhandled exception");
};

Tested both ways and both make no difference in this case.
But both work when I try to emulate "Out of Memory":
string value = new string('f', int.MaxValue);

This line of code results in identical logs being created when there is no custom handler for UnhandledException.
After searching for a solution I got an impression that this should work. What am I missing? Perhaps I need to configure Serilog in special manner for this to work?
Perhaps I need to use different logging solution. But this will be problematic.

Logging "out of memory" would need memory you don't have.

@Ralf, this closes the case rather quickly.

You can try to to do an extra memory thin logging to the console or to the Eventlog that might still work but collecting context info to make a relevant log might get you back to the inherent "you have no memory to do so" problem. So in the end you might have something then that has as much info as the eventlog entry you already have.

And surely you should profile the memory usage. OutOfMemory is sometimes misleading as it does not really mean that always. It just says a operation that needed memory couldn't get any. But if the operation asked for Multi GB of continuous memory it does not mean there isn't any memory left just there isn't a large enough memory block to fulfill the memory operation asked for.

True. But this cease is an actual verifiable memory leak

@InfernumDeus the vast majority of times I've seen people report a memory leak, it has turned out to be their app/code holding onto things accidentally; the way to solve that is with a memory profiling tool that can track the roots of long-lived objects

See When is it OK to catch an OutOfMemoryException and how to handle it?, you shouldn't normally be catching it unless you have a specific large array allocation you want to handle. If there is a memory leak you should be solving that instead using a memory profiler. See also the docs for info on how to handle it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.outofmemoryexception?view=net-8.0#remarks

Thanks a lot. I mostly got down to the cause. It's related to unmanaged memory and particular external library.

Use a profiler to see what's actually going on. Why is that library using so much memory? Does it require some extra action to release or reuse buffers? Does the .NET code pass new buffers to it when it could reuse the same one?

The short answer - not enough memory to perform logging.

Not really. This almost always means the application is leaking so much memory due to bad idioms that there's not enough contiguous memory to generate new strings or new buffers. String operations create new strings, so name1 + name 2 + name3 generates 2 extra temporary strings. Loading a CSV, splitting by line and separator, generates a lot of extra strings and ends up using 3 times as much RAM as the entire file. Adding 1M items to a List<> one by one results in Log2(1M)=19 reallocations, taking twice as much RAM

In all cases there are better alternatives that don't require extra allocations. Using eg CsvReader to read data one record at a time takes no more RAM than that single record, even if there are millions of rows
